# Is it possible to draw multiple SVG's to a canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg

### Background

I've got a bunch of `svg`'s in a document (with `rect`, `path`, and whatnot inside each) and I need to draw this out to a downloadable PNG image.  I understand that in order to do this there are two methods: either draw the page's HTML structure to a `canvas` and then export from there **or** render an SVG and its contents straight onto a `canvas`.

### Hypotheses

The first hypothesis I tried to render the HTML structure using [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com) and only found out that SVG's could not be rendered via an HTML structure at all (due to security issues).  The second hypothesis I tried to render an SVG to canvas via [canvg](https://code.google.com/p/canvg/) only to find out that it only allowed for one SVG element to be rendered and that only the first one would be rendered.

### Results

To prove the first one wrong, type in `http://www.w3schools.com/svg/tryit.asp?filename=trysvg_rect` to [this URL](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/screenshots.html) and disable Javascript.  To prove the second one wrong I have a [fiddle to try out](http://jsfiddle.net/qDmhV/124/).

---

### The Question

I want to make it clear that my reasoning for having multiple `svg`'s is so that I can place them within a responsive grid system and resize via aspect ratio.  Without further ado, I ask my question: **How can you render multiple `svg` elements to a `canvas`?**  If the answer to that question is "it isn't possible", then next my question would be: **Should I be rendering one `svg` instead and handle responsiveness another way?**

Comment: Another option is [Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com) which can not only parse and display SVG but also creates object model, allowing to change objects programmatically and/or via controls. I loaded your example in http://fabricjs.com/kitchensink/ (3rd tab — "Load SVG") and used "Load without grouping". Both rectangles are rendered on canvas; then you can do anything you want with them, including getting an image of a canvas.

Comment: @kangax: Wow, that's pretty cool. I dig it. I'll be sure to check that out, nice work!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to draw SVG to canvas just as any other image:

```
var img1 = document.createElement('img'),
    img2 = document.createElement('img')
    count = 2;

/// image loading is async, make sure they are loaded
img1.onload = img2.onload = function() {
    count--;
    if (count === 0) drawImages();
}
img1.src = 'some1.svg';
img2.src = 'some2.svg';

/// when loaded, draw them somewhere on the canvas
function drawImages() {
    ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
    ctx.drawImage(img2, someX, someY);
}
```

That being said - there are a couple of restrictions:

- FireFox currently does not want to [draw images properly](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=779368) without width and height set inside the SVG file.
- [CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) applies if you want to extract images as bitmap (`toDataURL`/`getImageData`). If not they should work as normal.

Comment: I don't see why this wouldn't work, so I'll make it correct. However, I should let people know that I decided to avoid this difficulty altogether and instead render things in one `svg` element. I am going to handle responsive by showing and hiding graphs based on Javascript detected screen width breakpoints to avoid having to generate all the `svg`'s and then hiding a few and cluttering the DOM.

Comment: FWIW, this doesn't work across all browsers (mainly older FF, Opera 12 & mobile, Android <=2.3). You can see it on my test page — http://kangax.github.io/jstests/canvas-drawimage-svg/

Comment: @kangax as I mention in the answer there are issues (particular with FF). Canvas and SVG are relative new features and still not set in stone (not final status, http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html). Don't expect it to work in older browsers.